# How to build Google RE2 for Windows?

Tags: c++, regex, windows, re2

How to build Google RE2 for Windows? Somebody tried?

Comment: What compiler are you using? RE2 will not build on MinGW because MinGW does not implement the full C++ standard. (and wchar_t stuff in particular)

Comment: @Billy ONeal, I use MSVC 2010. But can look for another one.

Comment: @user: MSVC should work AFAIK. Google doesn't provide a makefile for it but you should just be able to build as you would any other C++ library.

Comment: @Billy ONeal, It misses some files, at least 'sys/time.h', 'sys/resource.h' and 'pthread.h'

Comment: there is a [pthreads implementation](http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32) for win32. For the rest, you could write your implementation in terms of win32 functions (possibly starting with dummy implementations for non-essential calls).

Comment: @Billy ONeal The one I downloaded from their site has `wchar_t`, as far as I remember (and there were "special" builds by someone not directly affiliated with MinGW earlier (at least 2-3 years ago), as I remember getting them just for that reason). Anyway, building Google C++ stuff on windows is painless only with MS compilers, using MinGW is always problematic (incl. cross-compiling with GCC on Linux -- see code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/FAQ#Can_I_use_Google_Test_on_MinGW?  (that's for GoogleTest, mentions cross-compiling)).

Comment: @mlvljr: It supports the datatype `wchar_t`, but it's missing some things like `char_traits<wchar_t>`, `wstringstream`, etc. Perhaps that's changed since the last time I played with it, but AFAIK Boost.XPressive still is unable to build on that compiler because it's missing those bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE: found a Windows project which may or may not work better: https://code.google.com/p/re2win/

Old answer (non MSVC): https://groups.google.com/group/re2-dev/browse_thread/thread/0665d7e6693b4adb/54bae4e315a484e3

Comment: An answer for MSVC would be preferable, since this is windows.

Comment: So odd seeing "unixman" asking for MSVC. Isn't that heresy? lol

Comment: re2win does sure work but does anyone know of a more up to date windows port?

Answer (score 13):

I made a fork available at **http://code.google.com/p/re2win** you can download the source as a .zip file and open the `.vcproj` file and compile in 'Release' mode.

Comment: How to build it? What tools are required?

Comment: Great stuff. Will try it now.

Comment: I'm trying to get pyre2 working for Python. re2 is a prerequisite, i've built re2 for windows above in release mode but I'm unsure how to install it. I tried using the 'make' command using cygwin but i keep getting scope errors for the write func. Can anyone spell out how I get this installed for python?

Answer (score 1):

I bet it would build easily using [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com).

Comment: I wouldn't exactly call Cygwin "on windows" though, just as Wine isn't "on Unix".

Answer (score 1):

You can build RE2 for Windows with Microsoft Visual Studio by the Bazel build tool https://bazel.build/

0. Get the latest version of RE2 by `git clone https://github.com/google/re2.git`
1. Download Bazel Windows binary at https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases (scroll down and look for an .exe file)
2. Put the Bazel binary in the root directory of RE2, or add a directory with the Bazel binary to %PATH%.
3. Run the Visual Studio command prompt from the Start Menu, e.g., the the "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt"
4. In the command prompt, go to your RE2 root folder, e.g. `cd c:\gitrepos\re2`
5. Run `bazel.exe build :all`
6. Bazel will create the subdirectoris `bazel-bin`, `bazel-out`, `bazel-re2`, `bazel-testlogs`.
7. You will find the compiled RE2 binaries, i.e. the library and the test programs  (.lib, .pdb, .exe) at `bazel-bin`
8. Optionally, you may run test programs, e.g. `regexp_benchmark.exe`. You will see the output like that:

```
Search_Easy0_CachedDFA/8    10000000           105 ns/op      75.71 MB/s
Search_Easy0_CachedDFA/16   20000000           107 ns/op     148.31 MB/s
Search_Easy0_CachedDFA/32   20000000           121 ns/op     262.31 MB/s
Search_Easy0_CachedDFA/64   20000000           122 ns/op     523.80 MB/s
Search_Easy0_CachedDFA/128  20000000           120 ns/op    1061.91 MB/s
Search_Easy0_CachedDFA/256  20000000           122 ns/op    2081.69 MB/s
Search_Easy0_CachedDFA/512  10000000           185 ns/op    2760.31 MB/s
Search_Easy0_CachedDFA/1K   10000000           270 ns/op    3786.29 MB/s
Search_Easy0_CachedDFA/2K    5000000           409 ns/op    4995.25 MB/s
Search_Easy0_CachedDFA/4K    5000000           573 ns/op    7143.45 MB/s
Search_Easy0_CachedDFA/8K    1000000          1144 ns/op    7159.05 MB/s
Search_Easy0_CachedDFA/16K   1000000          1887 ns/op    8680.17 MB/s
Search_Easy0_CachedDFA/32K    500000          3620 ns/op    9049.65 MB/s
Search_Easy0_CachedDFA/64K    500000          7411 ns/op    8842.68 MB/s

etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Since September 2015 a CMakeLists.txt was added to RE2 repository. So now you can use [CMake](https://cmake.org/) to generate files for Visual Studio and then build like a normal Visual Studio project. I have written a simple [step-by-step tutorial](http://dfs-minded.com/2016/12/build-integrate-re2-c-project-windows/) on how to build and integrate RE2 in your C++ project for Windows. Tested for VS 13 and 15.

Comment: The link is broken. The correct link for the step by step tutorial is https://dfs-minded.com/build-integrate-re2-c-project-windows/